# split columns with different amount of values

Tags: r, multiple-columns, tidyr

I want to split 1 column into 3 columns. The Problem is that if I split the column by the seperator "," it sometimes containts 3 values and sometimes 2.

The output should look like the following:

```
  rooms                          location           Street   Suburb    City  price m2
1     2           examplestreet 3, munich             <NA>     <NA>  munich 500000 40
2     3                   suburg2, berlin             <NA>  suburg2  berlin 300000 60
3     5 examplestreet 45, suburb1, munich examplestreet 45  suburb1  munich 350000 55
```

Here is what I did:

```
   > rooms = c(2, 3, 5) 
> location = c("examplestraße 3, munich", "suburb2, berlin", "examplestaße 45, suburb1, munich") 
> price = c(500000, 300000, 350000) 
> m2 = c(40, 60, 55) 
> 
> dataexample = data.frame(rooms, location, price, m2)
> dataexample
  rooms                         location  price m2
1     2          examplestraße 3, munich 500000 40
2     3                  suburb2, berlin 300000 60
3     5 examplestaße 45, suburb1, munich 350000 55
> rooms = c(2, 3, 5) 
> location = c("munich", "suburb2, berlin", "examplestaße 45, suburb1, munich") 
> price = c(500000, 300000, 350000) 
> m2 = c(40, 60, 55) 
> 
> dataexample = data.frame(rooms, location, price, m2)
> 
> library(tidyr)
> separate(dataexample, location, into=c('Street', 'Suburb', "City"), remove=FALSE, sep = ",")
  rooms                         location          Street   Suburb    City  price m2
1     2                           munich          munich     <NA>    <NA> 500000 40
2     3                  suburb2, berlin         suburb2   berlin    <NA> 300000 60
3     5 examplestaße 45, suburb1, munich examplestaße 45  suburb1  munich 350000 55
Warning message:
Too few values at 2 locations: 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `base R` by splitting the 'location' column by the delimiter (`,`), pad with NAs for the `list` element that have few elements, `rbind` the `list` elements and `cbind` with the original dataset

```
lst <- strsplit(as.character(dataexample$location), ", ")
cbind(dataexample, `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(lst, 
      `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))), 
        function(x) c(x[is.na(x)], x[!is.na(x)]))), c('Street', 'Suburb', "City")))
#  rooms                         location  price m2          Street  Suburb   City
#1     2                           munich 500000 40            <NA>    <NA> munich
#2     3                  suburb2, berlin 300000 60            <NA> suburb2 berlin
#3     5 examplestaße 45, suburb1, munich 350000 55 examplestaße 45 suburb1 munich
```